# VSCode + Unity's test framework?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, nunit

I installed VSCode for Unity game development a few weeks ago and have been using it as an alternative to my usual setup of VS + Resharper. I enjoy VSCode quite a bit, especially given how fast and lightweight it is.

One problem I have, however, is writing tests. It's standard practice at our studio to create unit tests for certain features we implement, and we so we have an assembly for running tests in a Unity project.

There's a testing .asmdef that references the NUnit framework DLL and the assembbly that has the code I want to test. In VS, if I navigate through the code, it all looks fine. If I switch to VSCode, however, it tells me there's compilation errors all over the place, because VSCode can't see any of the NUnit classes or the classes from the assembly I want to test (in Unity, I get 0 compilation errors even when writing new code).

Is there any VSCode setup I can do to get rid of the compilation errors and write tests normally, or do I have to switch to VS to write tests?

Comment: Are you using [Unity's TestFramework](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html)?

Comment: Yes I am. Managed to find a solution with the help of a work colleague. Will post as answer so other people can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: A work colleague helped me out and linked me [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.dotnet-test-explorer) which clears up the compilation errors.

It looks like it lets me run tests from the IDE, too, but I haven't set it up yet as I just run them from Unity's Test Runner window. This isn't a priority for me, so I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: For update, you can add comment and/or edit your question. I suggest you to self-answer only when it solve your problem, and that you're sure it solve it

Comment: I've been using the extension since I last wrote about it, it works fine for writing tests and running them from Unity. This was what I was looking for, so I'll mark it as answer.